# How do I set up SSH over the internet?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I think this type of questions were answered before but due to lack of networking knowledge, for a couple of years I searched the internet and read many websites in an attempt to connect to an SSH server over the internet. But I have failed. I want to know if it is possible to connect two systems using SSH without using third party services like ngrok.

I have two computers running ArchLinux.
Computer A and B are inside a local network but I want to set up the ssh so that I can access A from B via SSH over the internet (like how Anydesk, Teamviewer and other such remote desktop software connects).

**Systems Details:**
1. The systems are connected to a [Digisol] router.
2. Both have `openssh` package installed. System A is running `sshd`. A can get connected to B over the LAN.

Hostname of system A: archlinux-pc

Hostname of system B: archlinux

On both the systems the username is *sourav*. That is, I want to connect to *sourav* on *archlinux-pc*.

3. Set up Virtual Server configuration on the router (Digisol):

```
Current Virtual Server Forwarding Table
ServerName  Protocol    Local IP Address    Local Port  WAN Port    State   Action
SSH     tcp     192.168.2.9     22-22   22-22   Enable
```

4. My public IP is xx.xxx.171.113 as reported by [ident.me](https://ident.me). The IP doesn't change in a period of many months.

whatismyipaddress.com shows the same IPv4 but *IPv6: Not detected*

My router has a section called WAN Configuration which shows some different IP:

```
WAN Configuration
Interface   Protocol    IP Address  Gateway     DNS     Status
WAN     PPPoE   xx.xxx.18.27    xx.xxx.0.1  xxx.xxx.91.2 8.8.8.8 xxx.xxx.88.2   Link Up(PPPoE)
```

---

I have already tried using `ssh sourav@xx.xxx.171.113` from system B, which takes a long time but doesn't connect at all.

I have also tried these links:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13861/setting-up-ssh-over-internet-on-my-pi

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding

---

How do I get connected to system A from system B using SSH without any other services like ngrok if something like that is possible? Also, can I connect to system A over SSH using termux running on my Android phone?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both systems are on the same local network, behind the same router:

Connecting to
sourav@xxx.xxx.171.113 will get you to 192.168.2.9

from there you can ssh to the next system, using it's local address (presumably 192.168.2.X)

If you want to access it externally, you have to add an additional port forward:

```
ServerName  Protocol    Local IP Address    Local Port  WAN Port    State   Action
       SSH       tcp         192.168.2.9         22-22     22-22    Enable  
      SSH2       tcp         192.168.2.X         22-22 63000-63000  Enable
```

Now you should be able to connect to sourav@xxx.xxx.171.113 port 63000 and reach the other system. It is good to move to a non default SSH port to lower the amount of brute force login attempts that you are going to receive from having your service available like this.

Comment: If the ports do not open on your WAN IP (xxx.xxx.171.113), more information is required to provide a valid answer. Please provide as much of your network topology as you can to assist in getting a good answer (less speculation).

You may be behind a double NAT or your ISP may have a type of configuration that is getting in the way. If this is the case you can still achieve what you are after using a reverse connect, this is achievable through SSH tunneling, but things get a little more complicated.

Comment: Hi, I have tried `ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:22 sourav@xx.xxx.171.113` as stated in this video: https://youtu.be/AtuAdk4MwWw

I am not using any firewall. I am not sure if I am behind double NAT. The computers are connected to a local router (Digisol DG-HR3300) which is connected to the internet.

Comment: Where are you making that connection attempt from? Can you verify that any of your port forwards are working? (Try using something like nmap and port scanning) If they are forwarded in the router and still showing as filtered, no connection will get through. If the ISP is filtering common ports, maybe uncommon ones will work (such as 63000), you will have to test and see.. add that forwarding rule and try connecting to it / running a portscan. If you still can't get a port open, you may be out of luck (look into using ngrok or set up a tor hidden service for nat punching)

Comment: I am trying to connect from the local ports for testing but I want anyone to connect to my PC via SSH for the time being (I will harden the systems later on). I do think that I am behind carrier grade NAT because my Router's WAN IP doesn't match the Public IP reported online. Nmap detects the ports and I can successfully login with the WAN IP shown by the router but not using the public IP. The ISP is claiming that they do not filter out any port.

Answer (score 1):

Implement IPv6 addressing. Add AAAA records to DNS. Open the port in your firewall. No NAT required.

To remove the chance of your prefix changing, get a static allocation from your ISP.